# Not plotting the axis of a chart if data is NA?

Tags: excel

I am plotting a chart according to a table with dates ranging from Jan 2011 to Jan 2020. The table extracts data live from another sheet and fills in whatever data that is available.

May I know how I can omit the plotting of the axis from 2017 - 2020 if there is no data present in the cells yet? Currently it plots the axis from 2017-2020 even though there is no data yet, is it possible for me to omit the plotting of that part of the axis until a data is present in the respective cell?

[image: Screenshot of my chart]

Thank you! Appreciate all the help  I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

You need to create two dynamic range names that extend to only the rows with data and use these range names as the source of the chart axis and chart value.

A detailed step by step has been created by Debra Dalgleish and published on Jon Peltier's site [here](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/DynamicColumnChart1.html)

If you have questions after following the steps described in the article, please pipe up.

Edit after comment: The beauty with dynamic range names is that there are many ways to construct them, depending what best works with your data set. If you have dates as the labels and the chart should only extend to the current month, you can use the date in the dynamic range for the labels and offset the range names for the series from that name.

Create these two range names:

```
chtXLabels  =Sheet1!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(TODAY(),Sheet1!$A:$A,1))
chtSeries1  =OFFSET(chtXLabels,0,1)
```

Edit the chart, set the category to `=Sheet1!chtXLabels` and set the series to `=Sheet1!chtSeries1`, using your sheet name, of course.
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. However, I have a problem with the dynamic range as my "empty cells" contain the function NA(). =IF(Value=0,NA(),Value). also I may have data points that skips a month. For e.g.

Jan 2011     10
Feb 2011     20
Mar 2011
Apr 2011     40

Comment: I added another way to create the dynamic range.